# PHP query not working using form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This is my query for inserting:

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['txtemail']);

    $str = "insert into subscribe(email,datetime) values ('$email',current_timestamp)";
    $result = mysql_query($str);

    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
            print 'alert("Thank you for subscribing with us. We will be in touch with you very soon.")';
            print '</script>';  


}
```

this is code above is perfectly working, but when i put a value on the form action to redirect to another page like this, the query is not inserting.

```
<form action="/?sender=nopopup" method="POST">
```

I tried using header(location: 'url'), but its not working also.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

This is my whole code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chill PH</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/popup.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/popup.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<div id="overlay"></div>

<center>
<div id="popup">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?sender=nopopup" method="POST">
<table style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
<tr>
<a href="#" onclick="closePopUp()"><img src="images/popup/chill_closebtn.png" style="width:30px; height:30px; vertical-align: top; 
margin-left: 583px; margin-top: -12px; position:fixed;"/></a>
    <img src="images/popup/chill_popup.jpg"/>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 594px; height: 111px;">
        <input id="txtemail" type="email" font-size= "12px" name="txtemail" placeholder="E-mail Address" 
        style="background-color:#f1c4c0; border-style:none; height:40px; width:270px; margin-left:60px; border-style:none; font-size: 15px;" required/>
        <input type="submit" id="subcribe_button" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</center>

<body onload="showPopUp()">
<center>
<div id="container">
    <table id="header">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center>
                    <div id="logo" style="color: #ff0000;">
                        <a href="/?sender=nopopup"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Chill" style="width: 130px;" /></a>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </td>        
            <td style="float: left; width: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                <div id="searchbox">
                    <form name="frmsearch" method="POST" action="/?sender=result">
                    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" size=20 placeholder="Search" style="background-color: white; float: right; color: black; border: 1px solid #000;"/>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style="display: none;visibility: hidden;" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                    
            <td align='center'>
                <div id="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li style="padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 40px;"><a href="#">WHAT'S HOT<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="shopitems"><a href="/?sender=shop&category=newarrivals">New Arrivals</a></li>
                                                                    <li class="shopitems"><a href="/?sender=shop&category=sale">Sale Items</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;"><a href="#">COLLECTION<span class="drop-down"></span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="shopitems"><a href="/?sender=shop&category=DRESS">Dresses</a></li>
                                <li class="shopitems"><a href="/?sender=shop&category=TOPS">Tops</a></li>
                                <li class="shopitems"><a href="/?sender=shop&category=SKIRTS">Skirts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;"><a href="/?sender=lookbook" class="lookbook">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
                        <li style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;"><a href="/?sender=news">NEWS</a></li>
                        <li style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 30px;"><a href="/?sender=store">STORES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


<?php
    require_once "config.php";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['txtemail']);

    $str = "insert into subscribe(email,datetime) values ('$email',current_timestamp)";
    $result = mysql_query($str);

    print '<script type="text/javascript">';
            print 'alert("Thank you for subscribing with us. We will be in touch with you very soon.")';
            print '</script>';  


    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?sender=nopopup" method="POST">
```

The `/` is making it post to the root of your website, not the current URL. [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the path of the current script relative to the document root.

Comment: i'm sorry sir but it's not working, the alert box is not also showing

Comment: thank you for the help sir but its not working also, i edited my question and put my whole code maybe this will also help, sorry i'm just new to php and web programming.